# Baked cloth and particle simulation not rendering at all

Tags: rendering

I have three cloth simulations, one particle simulation with an object selected as the particle sample, I have rendered both successfully before, but after I messed around in my world shader setting and added a camera route, all the simulations has stopped working and stayed as it is on frame 0, as if blender can't read the baked cache. I'm using Mac, Blender 2.9.

I have a feeling that this has nothing to do with my file, but is a bug? Please tell me which part of the settings I should look into and fix this, thanks.

edit: both eevee and cycle has this bug
please test this file and tell me if it works on your Blender as pleased, thank you.
[image]

Comment: The simulation works for me in v2.91. I see the camera moving towards the door and a lot of stuff flying around.

Comment: You can click the "Delete Cache" button in the cache settings, and then set the value for "Simulation End" to 1, then back to 500 (cache settings). This should clear everything in the cache.

Comment: @Blunder thanks, but that would also delete my baked cache?

Comment: I installed 2.91 and the render run fine, this is so odd, but i guess the problem is solved